# Delete any string and rewrite

Tags: tcl

I want to delete any string from my file but I am still stuck.

;#First text for delete

```
set findFirstText [format {test test
test test
test test
}]
```

;#Second text for delete

```
set findSecondText "second text"
```

;#

```
  set controlText [list A B]
    foreach lst $controlText  {
      set openFl [open "data.dat" r]
      set WriteFl [open "data.new" w]
      gets $openFl line
      while {![eof $openFl]} {
          if {$lst == "A"} {
              set ndx [string first $findFirstText $line]
           }
           if {$lst == "B"} {
              set ndx [string first $findSecondText $line]
           }
           if {$ndx > -1} {
             set chr [string length [string trim $line]]
             gets $openFl line
           }
           puts $WriteFl $line
           gets $openFl line
      }
      close $openFl 
      close $WriteFl
      file copy -force "data.new" "data.dat"
      file delete -force "data.new"
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very unclear. Please show the input and output files.

Comment: You won't be able to find multiline strings by looking at a file one line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest mechanism for doing this by far is to load the whole file into memory and use a whole-string search-and-replace.

```
set transform {}
lappend transform $findFirstText ""
lappend transform $findSecondText ""

set f [open "data.dat" r]
# Best to apply the transform immediately; enables better memory management
set data [string map $transform [read $f]]
close $f

set f [open "data.new" w]
puts -nonewline $f $data
close $f
```

The above only works when you can make the text to find a literal string and you are replacing it with another (e.g., the empty string). If you need to find a more complex pattern (e.g., a line *containing* some string) then you're better off using regular expressions:

```
# Assume no RE metacharacters in the target string; letters, numbers and whitespace all OK
set RE "^.*(?:$findFirstText|$findSecondText).*$"

set f [open "data.dat" r]
set data [regsub -all -line -- $RE [read $f] "" data]
close $f

set f [open "data.new" w]
puts -nonewline $f $data
close $f
```

Being able apply the transform to the whole file contents in one go remains the key to getting decent speed, provided the file is “small”. On most modern computers a few hundred megabytes of file is still small enough to be “small”.

Comment: You can write back over by changing the filename in the write, or do a `file rename` afterwards; the latter is best, especially if you've got an independent way to validate that the change was good before you overwrite the original.